# Replace dataframe values based on multiple conditions of different length's

Tags: python, pandas

I am able to replace dataframe values based on conditions of similar length, but I have not been able to successfully use a one-liner for conditions of different lengths. See below:

This approach works for conditions of similar length:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Name':['name1', 'name2', 'name3', 'name4', 'name2', 'name3', 'name4', 'name2', 'name2' ], 
                   'Block':['Block 1','Block 1','Block 1', 'Block 1','Block 2','Block 2', 'Block 2','Block 3','Block 4'], 
                   'Rotation':['ERJD','PEDI','MAM','PEDI', 'ERJD','PEDI','MAM','ERJD','ABD'],
                  })

df.loc[df['Name'].eq('name2') & df['Block'].eq('Block 3'), 'Rotation'] = 'VAC'
```

which generates

```
    Name    Block   Rotation
0   name1   Block 1 ERJD
1   name2   Block 1 PEDI
2   name3   Block 1 MAM
3   name4   Block 1 PEDI
4   name2   Block 2 ERJD
5   name3   Block 2 PEDI
6   name4   Block 2 MAM
7   name2   Block 3 VAC
8   name2   Block 4 ABD
```

Lets say for name2 i want to replace the Rotation to 'VAC' for both Block 3 and Block 4...Any suggestions for a one-liner?

I tried using a similar approach below, but cant get it to work.

```
df.loc[df['Name'].eq('name2') & df['Block'].eq(['Block 3','Block 4']), 'Rotation'] = 'VAC'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change the `eq` to `isin`

```
df.loc[df['Name'].eq('name2') & df['Block'].isin(['Block 3','Block 4']), 'Rotation'] = 'VAC'
```

Comment: Great, exactly what i was looking for. Thanks!